# How to let z3 command line output the mode (or unsat core) rather than sat/unsat?

Tags: z3, sat

`z3 -smt2 <filename>` only outputs 'sat' or 'unsat'. I would like that Z3 outputs the model if the constraint is satisfied, or the unsat core if unsatisfied. Which options of Z3 should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no command line options for this as in SMTLIB2 they are separate commands, `(get-model)` and `(get-unsat-core)`, both only defined when `(check-sat)` returns sat or unsat respectively.

The options `model` and `unsat-core` have to be enabled irrespective of whether those or other commands are used, just to make the solver tracks the right information, otherwise the `(get-model)` and `(get-unsat-core)` commands may fail later.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph. That makes sense.